# Помогите с версткой

Tags: css, вёрстка, html

Нужно, что-бы div1 оставался на левом листе, а div2 - на правом.
[источник](http://momentomori.ru)

```css
 html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #212121;
            background-image: url('http://momentomori.ru/img/book2.jpg');
            background-size: auto 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
        }

        .container {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .div1 {
            width: 30%;
            min-height: 150px;
            background: #ccc;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 20%;
        }

        .div2 {
            width: 28%;
            min-height: 150px;
            background: #c00;
            margin-left: 53%;
        }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
    <div class="div2">div2</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: задайте блокам минимальную ширину `min-width`

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот так собственно это делается

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section {
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url(http://momentomori.ru/img/book.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.clear,
.clear:after,
.clear:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
aside,
article {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.aside-block {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 20px 60px;
}
.article-block {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.aside-block,
.article-block {
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="clear">
  <aside>
    <div class="aside-block">
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
      <p>Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla quis lorem
        ut libero malesuada feugiat. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.</p>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <article>
    <div class="article-block">
      <h3>After Hours Programming</h3>
      <p>
        <p>After Hours Programming created this application. JavaScript has the awesome power to manipulate DOM elements on the fly. Default text creates the illusion of real text. People tend to read writing. People tend to read writing. This text will
          not appear in a consistent order. However, standard default text can do the trick. Humans are creative beings. That is preciously how this string was constructed. It looks even better with you using this text.</p>
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

> http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/mAdgpZ?editors=110

Comment: Спасибо, но тогда эта книга будет не резиновой на весь экран,как была.  Похоже min-height, можно задать через jquery исходя из разрешений экрана.

Comment: Вы проверьте, я же проверил

Answer (score 0):

добавил это код для задания min-height:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      height=$( window ).height()+'px';
      $('section').css('min-height', height);
        $( window ).resize(function() {
 height=$( window ).height()+'px';
      $('section').css('min-height', height);

        });
    });

</script>
```